# SelectItems returned null

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I am making a screen for system user account with group assignments. Each user will belong to the group that is registered thus limiting access to system features. Limiting longer works. All registration for new user was being done directly in the bank, and we agree this is nothing practical. But when trying to select the group to the user and move to variable that stores the group was chosen to be added to the user group list, the amount received by the same being "null" based on a print test of value received . I've walked researching but everywhere I look, my code is almost the same, I'm absolutely sure it's some detail I'm letting go unnoticed. Could see where I am going wrong?

View Cadastro.class

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/tema/LayoutPadrao.xhtml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">

<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="usuario" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario}" />
    <f:event listener="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.inicializar}"
        type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>

<ui:define name="titulo">#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando ? 'Edição de Usuário' : 'Cadastro de Novo Usuário'}</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">

    <h:form id="frmUsuario">
        <h1>#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando ? 'Edição de Usuário' :
            'Cadastro de Novo Usuário'}</h1>

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:toolbar style="margin-top:20px;">
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:button value="Novo" icon="ui-icon-circle-plus" />
                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                    id="botaoSalvar" action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.salvar}"
                    update="@form" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
                <p:button value="Pesquisa" icon="ui-icon-circle-zoomin" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px;"
            columnClasses="rotulo, campo, rotulo, campo">

            <f:facet name="header">
                Dados do Usuário do Sistema
            </f:facet>

            <p:outputLabel value="Matrícula:" for="matricula" />
            <p:inputText id="matricula" size="5"
                value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.matricula}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Nome do Usuário:" for="nome" />
            <p:inputText id="nome" size="50" maxlength="60"
                value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.nome}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Senha de Acesso:" for="senha1" />
            <p:password id="senha1" match="senha2" label="Senha" feedback="true"
                promptLabel="Digite sua senha" weakLabel="Fraca" goodLabel="Média"
                strongLabel="Forte" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Confirmação de senha:" for="senha2" />
            <p:password id="senha2" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.senha}"
                label="Confirmação de senha" />

            <p:outputLabel value="E-mail:" for="email" />
            <p:inputText id="email" size="50"
                value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.email}" />
            ############# Problema nessa parte ########
            ############# Inicio #####################
            <p:outputLabel value="Grupo" for="grupo" />
            <h:panelGroup>

                <p:selectOneMenu id="grupo"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.grupoSelecionado}"
                    style="width:160px;">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione ..." itemDisabled="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.gruposRaizes}"
                        var="grupo" itemValue="#{grupo}" itemLabel="#{grupo.descricao}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <p:commandButton value="Adicionar ao grupo"
                    style="margin-top: 10px; width:160px; margin-left: 5px"
                    action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.adicionarGrupo}" process="@this"
                    update="grupoTable" />

                <p:dataTable value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.listaGrupo}"
                    style="margin-top: 10px;"
                    emptyMessage="Usuário não pertence a nenhum grupo!"
                    id="grupoTable" var="item" rowIndexVar="linha">

                    <p:column headerText="Grupo" style="text-align: left; width: 100%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.descricao}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
             ########### Fim ########
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

CadastroUsuarioBean.class

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroUsuarioBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Usuario usuario;

private List<Grupo> listaGrupo = new ArrayList<>();

@Inject
private Grupos grupos;

@Inject
private CadastroUsuarioService cadastroUsuarioService;

private Grupo grupoSelecionado;

private List<Grupo> gruposRaizes;

public CadastroUsuarioBean() {
    limpar();
}

public void inicializar() {
    if (FacesUtil.isNotPostback()) {
        gruposRaizes = grupos.raizes();
    }
}

public void salvar() {

    this.usuario = cadastroUsuarioService.salvar(this.usuario);
    // limpar();

    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!");

}

private void limpar() {
    usuario = new Usuario();
    grupoSelecionado = new Grupo();
}

public void adicionarGrupo() {
    System.out.println("Grupo selecionado: " + grupoSelecionado.getDescricao());
    listaGrupo.add(grupoSelecionado);
}

public void removerGrupo(int linha){
    listaGrupo.remove(linha);
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public boolean isEditando() {
    return usuario.getMatricula() != null;
}

public List<Grupo> getGruposRaizes() {
    return gruposRaizes;
}

public void setGruposRaizes(List<Grupo> gruposRaizes) {
    this.gruposRaizes = gruposRaizes;
}

public Grupo getGrupoSelecionado() {
    return grupoSelecionado;
}

public void setGrupoSelecionado(Grupo grupoSelecionado) {
    this.grupoSelecionado = grupoSelecionado;
}

public List<Grupo> getListaGrupo() {
    return listaGrupo;
}

public void setListaGrupo(List<Grupo> listaGrupo) {
    this.listaGrupo = listaGrupo;
}

}
```

Grupos.class (Repository)

```
public class Grupos implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public List<Grupo> raizes() {
    return this.manager.createQuery("from Grupo", Grupo.class).getResultList();
}

public Grupo porId(Long id) {
    return this.manager.find(Grupo.class, id);
}

}
```

Grupo.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "grupo")
public class Grupo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String nome;
private String descricao;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@Column(nullable = false, length = 80)
public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Grupo other = (Grupo) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Recalling that the combobox filled out correctly with all the names of groups that are on the table group.

@Edit 19/07/2016

I do not know if not properly specified the problem. The problem is not display the value in SelectItens but by clicking the "Add Group" button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Adicionar ao grupo"
                style="margin-top: 10px; width:160px; margin-left: 5px"
                action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.adicionarGrupo}" process="@this"
                update="grupoTable" />
```

When calling the function

```
public void adicionarGrupo() {
    System.out.println("Grupo selecionado: " + grupoSelecionado.getDescricao());
    listaGrupo.add(grupoSelecionado);
}
```

In the application console is printed: "Grupo selecionado: null" instead of printing the value that was selected in selectitens

with the null object, it is not possible to display the datatable

```
<p:dataTable value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.listaGrupo}"
                    style="margin-top: 10px;"
                    emptyMessage="Usuário não pertence a nenhum grupo!"
                    id="grupoTable" var="item" rowIndexVar="linha">

                    <p:column headerText="Grupo" style="text-align: left; width: 100%">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.descricao}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Excluir" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Are you sure your list is being initialized?

Comment: as well I did not understand. [link] (http://i17.photobucket.com/albums/b87/forjefantasma/erro%20user.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, as he had imagined was a detail that was going unnoticed.

```
<p:commandButton value="Adicionar ao grupo"
            style="margin-top: 10px; width:160px; margin-left: 5px"
            action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.adicionarGrupo}" process="@this"
            update="grupoTable" />
```

This button that was responsible for making the value of SelectItens go to the variable "grupoSelecionado" was not processing the component "SelectItem" but only himself. For this reason the value of the variable was always null.

I changed the button, getting this way:

```
<p:commandButton value="Adicionar ao grupo"
                    style="margin-top: 10px; width:160px; margin-left: 5px"
                    action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.adicionarGrupo}" process="grupo, @this "
                    update="grupoTable" />
```

Thus the problem was solved and now I can register the system users by page created and no longer directly in the database.

Sorry I'm English, I'm still learning this language.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done a select item in the page like that. I've always created a function in the backing bean.

I use the values on the xhtml page like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="grupo"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.grupoSelecionado}"
                    style="width:160px;">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione ..." itemDisabled="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.getGroupRaizesSelectOne()}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

`getGroupRaizesSelectOne` looks like :

```
function SelectItem[] getGroupRaizesSelectOne()
{
    int len = this.groupRaizes.size();
    SelectItem[] selects = new SelectItem[len];

    for(Grupo group:gruopRaizes)
    {
        selects[i] = new SelectItem(group, group.getDescricao());
    }

    return selects;
}
```

We also had to have something line Omni-faces to convert our objects and allow them to be used as an object on the page.

Comment: I always use `<f:selectItems value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.groupRaizesSelectOne}"/>`for 'getters'

Comment: I added more details on the issue.